# Refreshing android systemui without reboot

Tags: android

How do I restart SystemUI in source code without rebooting the device?

I am trying to switch system font without rebooting, everything is OK except for SystemUI. I want to restart SystemUI immediately rather than reboot the device.

Thanks~~~

Comment: In addition, i am modifying in Android Source Code. Restart SystemUI is ok,but it will jump to Keyguard when restarted.  Refresh the view of systemui is the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requires root access, but you can restart System UI via this method:

```
private void restartSystemUi() {
    Process process = null;
    try { 
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving process", e);
    } 

    if (process != null ){
        try {
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());  
            os.writeBytes("pkill com.android.systemui\n"); 
            os.flush(); 
            os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
            os.flush(); 
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error killing system UI", e);
        } 
    } 
}
```

As with any root operations, your mileage may vary. It's not possible without root, so this (or similar privilege abuse) are your only option.

Answer (score 1):

call following method from where you want the rest the UI

```
private void restartSelf() {   
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 500, // one second   
    PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, getActivity().getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));  
    Intent i = getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageName());  
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
    startActivity(i);  
}
```

Comment: call this above method from where you want the rest the UI

Answer (score 0):

This because system creayes the SystemUI after boot and it will be alive until the system will be rebooted. And some configuration in SystemUI are Singleton which are being used by different part of that like volumeUI, etc. So, the only way is forcing it to be killed. But, to do that you need to access the root level. .